# i cannot run rails from anywhere else except home folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm having this strange problem

```
[user@host folder]$ rails -v
LoadError: no such file to load -- active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
(root) at /opt/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-        3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:1
 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
 (root) at script/rails:6
```

and then

```
[user@host ~]$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.8
```

This has been very troublesome for the past few days. I have seen the $PATH, i ran 'whichrails' and it is the same in both the cases. Why am i not able run atleast rails -v when iam in the 'folder' directory? Also, I cannot start a server or run rails new blog and it keeps saying this active_support error.

Any kind of suggestion regarding this will be very helpful

Comment: Are you running rvm?  Check your home folder for a ~/.rvmrc file.

Comment: @JD. no iam not running on rvm, there are no rights for me install rvm, im using jruby with rails; jruby -v 1.6.7.2 and rails 3.2.8

Comment: Knowing nothing about jruby, I can only guess that this machine needs either an environment variable set or some other way to tell it where 'active_support/core_ext/object/...' is.